# sscanf and multiple %ms

Tags: c, scanf

When `sscanf()` gets two "%ms" in the format string. 
Is it safe to call free() for both target pointers, when the `sscanf()` returns 0 or 1? Like in the next function:

```
void foo(const char* text)
{
    char* key = NULL;
    char* value = NULL;

    int count = sscanf(text, "%ms %ms", &key, &value);

    if (count == 2)
    {
        ...
    }

    free(key);
    free(value);
}
```

Or can the later target pointer (`value`) have some garbage value?
And the following cleanup is needed:

```
void bar(const char* text)
{
    char* key = NULL;
    char* value = NULL;

    int count = sscanf(text, "%ms %ms", &key, &value);

    if (count == 2)
    {
        ...
        free(key);
        free(value);
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        free(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the example and the explanation on the bottom: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf: `[...] it is only necessary to call free(3) if the scanf() call successfully read a string.`

Comment: @AndreKampling but the question was not whether it's *necessary*. OP was asking whether it would be *safe* to do it in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should be aware that `m` in a conversion specification is **non-standard**, so you should think about using it twice: Your code will be non-portable.

But then, if your implementation supports `m`, this usage is **safe** as long as you initialize your pointers to `0`/`NULL`. `scanf()` never touches anything when there's no conversion possible and `free(0)` is specified to be a *no op* (it's always safe).

Comment: Didn't know that: is `free(0)` safe by C standard? Could you please refer to that?

Comment: @AndreKampling see **§7.22.3.3 p2**: "*The free function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
available for further allocation. **If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.***"